# Tkinter .exe window duplicates when running my YOLO model

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, yolo, yolov8

I have a Tkinter application that has to analyze a picture with a custom yolo model. When the model is running the application freezes because the process is quite large. Then a duplicate item of the tkinter window opens. This only happens in a .exe file.

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from grabcut import getLengthBar
model = YOLO('best.pt')

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("My App")

        self.image_dir = ""
        self.image_files = []
        self.current_index = 0

        self.select_dir_button = tk.Button(master, text="Select Directory", command=self.select_directory)
        self.select_dir_button.pack()

        self.image_label = tk.Label(master)
        self.image_label.pack()

        self.prev_button = tk.Button(master, text="Previous", command=self.show_previous_image)
        self.prev_button.pack(side="left")

        self.next_button = tk.Button(master, text="Next", command=self.show_next_image)
        self.next_button.pack(side="right")

    def select_directory(self):
        self.image_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(self.image_dir) if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in (".jpg", ".png")]

        if self.image_files:
            self.current_index = 0
            self.show_image()

    def show_image(self):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, self.image_files[self.current_index])

        # Create a new thread to run the YOLO model
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_yolo_model, args=(image_path,))
        thread.start()

        thread.join()

        self.update_ui(image_path)

    def run_yolo_model(self, image_path):
        # Load the image and run it through the YOLO model
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        results = model.predict(image)

        # Store the results in an instance variable
        self.results = results

    def update_ui(self, image_path):
        # Process the image and display it in the GUI
        if not self.image_files:
            return

        results = self.results

        for r in results:
            masks = r.masks  # Masks object for segmentation masks outputs
            mask = masks.data[0].numpy()
            self.pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
            mask = mask.astype('uint8')  # Convert to uint8
            self.lengthRedBar= getLengthBar(image_path) 

            if self.lengthRedBar is None:
                print("Red bar not found. Skipping to the next image.")
                self.next_image()
                break 

            contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            if len(contours) != 0:
                # the contours are stored as a NumPy array of (x,y) coordinates of the boundary points of the object
                largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)  
                perimeter = cv2.arcLength(largest_contour, True)  # Perimeter in pixels

            im_array = r.plot()  # plot a BGR numpy array of predictions
            im = Image.fromarray(im_array[..., ::-1])  # RGB PIL image
            photo = im.resize((300, 300))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)

            # Display the image in the GUI
            self.image_label.config(image=photo)
            self.image_label.image = photo


    def show_previous_image(self):
        if self.image_files:
            self.current_index = (self.current_index - 1) % len(self.image_files)
            self.show_image()

    def show_next_image(self):
        if self.image_files:
            self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % len(self.image_files)
            self.show_image()

root = tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried using a thread and I also still think that is the solution but I just can not get it to work. I know the Tkinter application works because when I run it locally tkinter runs as intended. It us just the duplicate window.

Here a video that someone else made with the same question but it never got resolved.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ce_ZTL9vBm8

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Found the solution here: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/3997

Basically, all you have to do is add this before any other imports:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```